# how to show categories and subcategories from database

Tags: php, mysql

i need to fetch data from two tables one is category table and second is sub category table.
In subcategory table i am saving primary key of category table. Now i need to fecth array from the table. first i want to show category name and its subcategories and then second category and its subcategory. This is my code to get category and subcategory list.

```
include("admin/common/connection.php");
$userId= $_GET['user'];

if(isset($userId)) 
{
$select="select category_name,id from tbl_category where user_id='".$userId."'";
$query= mysql_query($select);
$var= array();
while($fetch_row= mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  $cat_dish= $fetch_row['category_name'];

  $var['category'] = $cat_dish;
  $select_dish="select dish_photo,printer_location,printer_list,kitchen_display from tbl_category_dish where user_id='".$userId."' and cat_id='".$fetch_row['id']."'";
  $query_dish= mysql_query($select_dish);
  while($row= mysql_fetch_array($query_dish))
  {

    $var['dish_photo']= $row['dish_photo'];
    $var['printer_location']= $row['printer_location'];

  }

}
print_r($var);

}
```

Comment: FYI, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and it is using the deprecated MySQL extension. I would advise you to switch to MySQLi or PDO. If you don't do so, at least use `mysql_real_escape_string()` for escaping the $_GET input variable.

Comment: Not solving your issue but you should use MySQL PDO instead of those deprecated mysql_ functions.

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/ Why you need PDO & how to use it

Comment: ok thanks i will change it in my code. but can you please tell me what i am doing wrong to get category and subcategory array.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is a JOIN statement.  The below statement would replace your two queries and instead just use this one.

```
SELECT cd.dish_photo,cd.printer_location,cd.printer_list,cd.kitchen_display,   
    cat.category_name, cat.id   
FROM tbl_category_dish AS cd  
LEFT JOIN tbl_category AS cat ON cd.cat_id = cat.id 
WHERE cd.user_id = '".$userId."'
```

These items may also help you learn and develop your skills.
1)  As stated above, try [PDO to prevent SQL injection](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).
2)  Examine the setup of your database table.  Learn about [database relations](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships/).

Answer (score 0):

not commenting on the insecurities in your method but answering the question, you can do this in one query

```
$sql="select 
    a.category_name,
    a.id,
    b.dish_photo,
    b.printer_location,
    b.printer_list,
    b.kitchen_display 
    from tbl_category a, 
    tbl_category_dish 
    where user_id='" . $userid . "' 
    and b.cat_id=a.id";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    if(!isset($var[$row["category_name"]])){
        $var[$row["category_name"]]=array();
    }
    $var[$row["category_name"]][]=$row;
}
print_r($var);
```

Comment: i have tried this but it is not showing all categories. it is showing only those categories which have subcategories. i need to show all categories weather it have subcat or not.